# How to use this true/false flag to make switching radio buttons disable other radio buttons effects

Tags: javascript, html

Ive tried following this:

```
var changed = function() {
        if (document.getElementById('wolf').checked) {
           wolfActive = true;
           turtleActive = false;
           lizardActive = false;

       } else if (document.getElementById('lizard').checked) {
           lizardActive = true;
          wolfActive = false;
           turtleActive = false;

       } else if (document.getElementById('turtle').checked) {
           turtleActive = true;
           lizardActive = false;
           wolfActive = false;

       }
   }
```

But i can't get each radiobuttons effect to be false when a different radio button is selected ( having a hard time understanding how it works)

This is my JavaScript:

```
var Turtle = 1;
var Turtlelv = 1;
var TurtleCexp = 0;
var TurtleMexp = 100;
var NextMaxTurtleExp = TurtleMexp;
var Turtleregen = 0.5;
var Lizard = 1;
var Lizardlv = 1;
var LizardCexp = 0;
var LizardMexp = 100;
var NextMaxLizardExp = LizardMexp;
var Wolf = 1;
var Wolflv = 1;
var WolfCexp = 0;
var WolfMexp = 100;
var NextMaxWolfExp = WolfMexp;
var Strength = 2;
var Magic = 1;
var Wolfstrength = 1
var ManaPoints = 10






function Wolfandstrength() {
  if (document.getElementById("wolf-radio").checked) {
    Strength = Strength + Wolfstrength
   document.getElementById("Strength").innerHTML = Strength;
  } else {
   Strength = Strength - Wolfstrength
   document.getElementById("Strength").innerHTML = Strength;
 }
  }


   function wolfXpUp() {
    if (document.getElementById("wolf-radio").checked && WolfCexp < WolfMexp) 
   {
      setTimeout(wolfXpUp, 100)
     WolfCexp = WolfCexp + 1;
     document.getElementById("WolfCexp").innerHTML = WolfCexp;
   } 
       if (WolfCexp >= WolfMexp) {
         Wolflv = Wolflv + 1;
         WolfCexp = 0;
         Wolf = Wolf + 1;
         Wolfstrength = Wolfstrength + 1;
         Strength = Strength + 1;
        NextMaxWolfExp= NextMaxWolfExp *1.5;
      }
    document.getElementById("Strength").innerHTML = Strength;
    document.getElementById('WolfMexp').innerHTML = NextMaxWolfExp;
    document.getElementById('Wolflv').innerHTML = Wolflv;
    document.getElementById('WolfCexp').innerHTML = WolfCexp;
    document.getElementById('Wolf').innerHTML = Wolf;
}

   function lizardXpUp() {
    if (document.getElementById("lizard-radio").checked && LizardCexp < 
   LizardMexp) {
       setTimeout(lizardXpUp, 200)
        LizardCexp = LizardCexp + 1;
       document.getElementById("LizardCexp").innerHTML = LizardCexp;
     } 
       if (LizardCexp >= LizardMexp) {
          Lizardlv = Lizardlv + 1;
          LizardCexp = 0;
          Lizard = Lizard + 1;
          Lizardmagic = Lizardmagic + 1;
          Magic = Magic + 1;
         NextMaxLizardExp= NextMaxLizardExp *1.5;
       }
          document.getElementById("Magic").innerHTML = Magic;
          document.getElementById('LizardMexp').innerHTML = 
   NextMaxLizardExp;
            document.getElementById('Lizardlv').innerHTML = Lizardlv;
            document.getElementById('LizardCexp').innerHTML = LizardCexp;
            document.getElementById('Lizard').innerHTML = Lizard;
        }

   function turtleXpUp() {
     if (document.getElementById("turtle-radio").checked && Turtleexp < 
   TurtleMexp) {
       setTimeout(turtleXpUp, 200)
       TurtleCexp = TurtleCexp + 1;
       document.getElementById("TurtleCexp").innerHTML = TurtleCexp;
     } 
        if (TurtleCexp >= TurtleMexp) {
          Turtlelv = Turtlelv + 1;
           TurtleCexp = 0;
          Turtle = Turtle + 1;
          Tmanapoints = Tmanapoints + 1;
          ManaPoints = ManaPoints + 1;
         NextMaxLizardExp= NextMaxLizardExp *1.5;
        }
       document.getElementById("ManaPoints").innerHTML = ManaPoints;
       document.getElementById('TurtleMexp').innerHTML = NextMaxTurtleExp;
       document.getElementById('Turtlelv').innerHTML = Turtlelv;
       document.getElementById('TurtleCexp').innerHTML = TurtleCexp;
       document.getElementById('Turtle').innerHTML = Turtle;
   }








document.getElementById("wolf-radio").addEventListener("change", wolfXpUp)   
document.getElementById("wolf-radio").addEventListener("change", 
Wolfandstrength)
document.getElementById("lizard-radio").addEventListener("change", 
lizardXpUp)
document.getElementById("lizard-radio").addEventListener("change", 
Wolfandstrength);
document.getElementById("Strength").innerHTML = Strength;   
document.getElementById("Magic").innerHTML = Magic;
document.getElementById("ManaPoints").innerHTML = ManaPoints;
```

HTML code: ( can change if needed its not perfect)

```
font size="+2"> <b> Pets </b></font>

<div id="turtle" class="control">
   <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="Pets" id="turtle-radio">
   </label><img src="turtle.png" alt="turtle" height="100" width="100"> Lv 
   <span id="Turtlelv">1</span> <span id="TurtleCexp">0</span> / <span 
  id="TurtleMexp">100</span>
      <br />
      <br />

       <div id="lizard" class="control">
         <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="Pets" id="lizard-radio">
        </label><img src="lizard.png" alt="lizard" height="42" width="42"> 
   &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Lv <span 
    id="Lizardlv">1</span> <span id="LizardCexp">0</span> / <span 
    id="LizardMexp">100</span>
       <br />
        <div id="wolf" class="control">
          <label class="radio">
           <input type="radio" name="Pets"  id="wolf-radio">
           </label><img src="wolf.png" alt="wolf" height="60" width="60"> 
    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Lv <span id="Wolflv">1</span> <span 
    id="WolfCexp">0</span> / <span id="WolfMexp">100</span></div>
       <br />
      <span id="Strength">0</span>
        <br />
      <span id="Magic">0</span>
           <br />
      <span id="ManaPoints">0</span>
```

I expect from using that true/false function in my what i've already tried box to help me disable radio buttons functions/ stat buffs while a diffrent radio button is selected. But the actual output when you switch from the turtle radio button to lizard radio button it takes away 1 strength when strength should be untouched unless the wolf radio button is selected.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: And what do you mean by this question, sorry but I don't understand. Are you trying to get the radio buttons to disable the other radio buttons so that only one option can be selected?

Comment: lets say you select the wolf radio button. its buffs / stat chanes should be the only thing effecting the player. if you change to the lizard radio button those buffs from the wolf radio buttion should go away. ( like if it was giving u 5 strength that strength should go back down to what it was before the radio button was selected) I posted a lot because I wanted all the buttons to have a sort of action they take when they are selected. sort of what my wolfandstrength function is doing but I want that to work for every radio button

Comment: I want switching to a radio button to make the other radio buttons false/ not affect the players stats. stat changes should only be in effect while the radio button is selected. Settime out does this perfectly because it stops when the radio button isnt selected. but im not sure how to take away the stat changes and put them back to what they where before the radio button was selected. I came across this type of function and thought it might work but having a hard time putting it into action  http://prntscr.com/nwtsk5  what i posted above .

Comment: I feel like it should work but im to new at this to know how to combine it with my code.